# java saaj Exception

Tags: java, soap, saaj

I try to create a Soap Envelope from String using

```
SOAPPart().setContent(Source).
```

And I try to get the SOAPBody from same message, but its throwing exception

```
SEVERE: SAAJ0511: Unable to create envelope from given source
com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Unable to create envelope from given source: 
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.EnvelopeFactory.createEnvelope(EnvelopeFactory.java:114)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPPart1_1Impl.createEnvelopeFromSource(SOAPPart1_1Impl.java:70)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SOAPPartImpl.getEnvelope(SOAPPartImpl.java:122)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageImpl.getSOAPBody(MessageImpl.java:1253)
    at mytransactions.Test.main(Test.java:107)
Caused by: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: XML-22103: (Fatal Error) DOMResult can not be this kind of node.
    at oracle.xml.jaxp.JXTransformer.reportException(JXTransformer.java:883)
    at oracle.xml.jaxp.JXTransformer.transform(JXTransformer.java:353)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.util.transform.EfficientStreamingTransformer.transform(EfficientStreamingTransformer.java:393)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.EnvelopeFactory.createEnvelope(EnvelopeFactory.java:102)
    ... 4 more

CAUSE:

javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: XML-22103: (Fatal Error) DOMResult can not be this kind of node.
    at oracle.xml.jaxp.JXTransformer.reportException(JXTransformer.java:883)
    at oracle.xml.jaxp.JXTransformer.transform(JXTransformer.java:353)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.util.transform.EfficientStreamingTransformer.transform(EfficientStreamingTransformer.java:393)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.EnvelopeFactory.createEnvelope(EnvelopeFactory.java:102)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPPart1_1Impl.createEnvelopeFromSource(SOAPPart1_1Impl.java:70)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SOAPPartImpl.getEnvelope(SOAPPartImpl.java:122)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageImpl.getSOAPBody(MessageImpl.java:1253)
    at mytransactions.Test.main(Test.java:107)

CAUSE:

javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: XML-22103: (Fatal Error) DOMResult can not be this kind of node.
    at oracle.xml.jaxp.JXTransformer.reportException(JXTransformer.java:883)
    at oracle.xml.jaxp.JXTransformer.transform(JXTransformer.java:353)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.util.transform.EfficientStreamingTransformer.transform(EfficientStreamingTransformer.java:393)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.EnvelopeFactory.createEnvelope(EnvelopeFactory.java:102)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPPart1_1Impl.createEnvelopeFromSource(SOAPPart1_1Impl.java:70)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SOAPPartImpl.getEnvelope(SOAPPartImpl.java:122)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageImpl.getSOAPBody(MessageImpl.java:1253)
    at mytransactions.Test.main(Test.java:107)
```

How to fix this?

Comment: this problem because of _oracle.xml.jaxp.JXTransformer.transform. I cant remove that jar file. How to force my application to use the default xml libraries?

Answer (score 0):

The Services API will look for a classname in the file META-INF/services/javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory in jars available to the runtime. I override this property using jvm -D option.